How to add padding to matplotlib plot when aspect is "equal"?
Whenever I make plots with plt.gca().set_aspect("equal"), the plot can become scrunched to the point where it appears collapse. How can I add some extra padding or retain padding while maintaining the aspect ratio?
A few examples:
# A Line
plt.plot([0, 0], [0, 100])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()


# A Line with a "tail"
plt.plot([0, 0, 0, 5], [0, 100, 200, 200])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()


# Two lines
plt.plot([0, 0], [0, 50])
plt.plot([0, 0], [50, 100])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()



Could you explain what exactly you are expecting the padding to look like? Maybe you could draw a mockup? Does it need to work in more general situations or only for the test cases shown?

I'm expecting there to be some space inside the graph to actually see the lines. For example the "tail" above has a padding above it. How to I add that for these plots? This is specific to when the aspect is fixed, so yes only the above cases.
For example adding "margins" does nothing.
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axes_margins.html

Maybe you want to look into ax.set_aspect(aspect="equal", adjustable="datalim"). Docs: aspect, adjustable

This is the correct answer. You should post it.

You can explicitly set the x-limits with ax.set_xlim, e.g.
# A Line
plt.plot([0, 0], [0, 100])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.set_xlim(-5, 5)
plt.show()



You can use ax.set box aspect() in conjunction with manually defining the bounds if you want a fixed aspect ratio with additional padding:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0, 0], [0, 100])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.set_box_aspect(1)
padding = 5
ax.set_xlim(-padding, padding)
ax.set_ylim(-padding, 100 + padding)
plt.show()

Output of the code:

